# Custom slider control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, controls

I am working on a WPF application that has to display a value on a slider (per requirement). The idea would be that this slider would have 6 properties. Three of them are the typical properties you would see on a slider control: a minimum limit, a maximum limit, and a value. However in addition to this I need to show an "inner range" of values that are acceptable (so a inner minimum limit, and inner maximum limit). Lastly the indicator should only show non-acceptable ranges for values over a threshold value. In the end what they are looking for is a control that looks something like this:

Example picture of a slide ruler
[image]

I was curious if anyone could point me in the direction of a good example on how to add extra properties to a control and customize the views to achieve something like this in Xaml. I have seen examples where people have added an extra value to the slide control to allow for selecting a minimum and maximum range of values.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should come back with a more specific problem. Generally you have to create a control which is composed of several controls like a `Thumb`, `Label` and drawings for the scale. You can create a `UserControl` or a custom control that derives from `Slider` to get the functionality and override the `ControlTemplate` to customize the appearance. See [Microsoft Docs: Control Customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-customization).

Comment: I am not sure how I can be more specific than explaining specifically every single property I need to add to a specific control in a specific way.That said thanks for answering.

Comment: I mean you should start to implement it. When you encounter any problems, you can post your code and ask for help. Regarding properties, you should learn about `DependencyProeprty`: [Microsoft Docs: Dependency properties overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). Then you know how to add properties to a `Control`. Read about `Style` and `ControlTemplate` by clicking the bottom last link in the content of the very first link I've posted (in my first comment). You need this to customize the appearance of the default `Slider`.

Comment: You don't even need to extend the `Slider` class, except you need more functionality or properties. In this case I recommend to create a new class that derives from Slider (instead of creating a `UserControl`). In the beginning just focus on how to modify the appearance first.

Comment: Ah I see you mean a more narrow question not a more specific question. Thanks for the starting points.

Comment: The content of first link also contains a section _Control Styles and Templates_. Visit this page and select _Slider Styles and Templates_. Then modify the style. The `Style` contains an element named _PART_Track_. This is bar on which the slider moves and which you want to colorize. The _SliderThumbStyle_ is used to style the thumb of the slider. Just replace the shape with a triangular shape.

Comment: Yes more narrow. And specific because you currently ask about many problems in one question. Pick a problem, explain it, post your coding attempt as a starting point to help you. You should tackle the big problem step by step. This is not meant to be rude. It's just impossible to answer such a broad question.